# Get XML response with PHP SOAPClient

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to replicate this structure using php native SoapClient functions

```
$client = new SoapClient('my.wsdl', ['trace'=>1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE]);
$client->MethodToCall($params);
var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

This is the expected xml request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
    <soapenv:Header/> 
    <soapenv:Body> 
        <MethodToCall> 
            <MethodToCallRQ> 
                <RqHeader HostID="123456" Xtoken="TOKEN123456" Interface="WEB" UserName="WEB"/> 
                <SearchType>NAME</SearchType> 
                <RecordCode/> 
                <Name>MARIO</Name> 
            </MethodToCallRQ> 
        </MethodToCall>
    </soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

At the moment I'm not able to reproduce it.
I need some hint to pass parameters in the right way to my method.

UPGRADE.

I used [wsdl2phpgenerator](https://github.com/wsdl2phpgenerator/wsdl2phpgenerator) to create all the class for my request.

My code result as below:

```
$service = new \SoapExtended(
    [
        'soap_version'   => SOAP_1_1,
        'exceptions'     => true,
        'trace'          => 1,
        'location'       => MYLOCATION,
        'cache_wsdl'     => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    ],
    MYWSDL
);

$params = new \MethodToCallRQ("NAME");
$params->setName("MARIO");
$params->setRqHeader(new \RequestHeader("123456", "TOKEN123456", "WEB", "WEB"));

$request = new \MethodToCall($params);
$response = $service->MethodToCall($request); 
// above call is equal to this below:
//$this->__soapCall('MethodToCall', array($request));
```

The dump of $request is:

```
object MethodToCall (1) {
    protected MethodToCallRQ -> object MethodToCallRQ (10) {
        protected SearchType -> string (4) "NAME"
        protected RecordCode -> NULL
        protected Name -> string (7) "Stefano"
        protected Surname -> NULL
        protected VatCode -> NULL
        protected ZipCode -> NULL
        protected City -> NULL
        protected CountyCode -> NULL
        protected CategoryCode -> NULL
        protected RqHeader -> object RequestHeader (5) {
            protected HostID -> string (6) "123456"
            protected Xtoken -> string (11) "TOKEN123456"
            protected Interface -> string (3) "WEB"
            protected UserName -> string (3) "WEB"
        }
    }
}
```

The resulting xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <parameters>
            <MethodToCallRQ>
                <SearchType>NAME</SearchType>
                <RecordCode/>
                <Name>Stefano</Name>
                <Surname/>
                <VatCode/>
                <ZipCode/>
                <City/>
                <CountyCode/>
                <CategoryCode/>
                <RqHeader>
                    <HostID>123456</HostID>
                    <Xtoken>TOKEN123456</Xtoken>
                    <Interface>WEB</Interface>
                    <UserName>WEB</UserName>
                </RqHeader>
            </MethodToCallRQ>
        </parameters>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Why tag

```
<parameters>
```

instead of

```
<MethodToCall>
```

?

Comment: `This is the expected xml request` - And what is the actual request?

Comment: I'm not sure that actual request will be useful, I tried a lot of combinations for $parameters (In my example I reported it only for clarity), and I wasn't able to reproduce the xml inside body.

Answer (score 0):

Having the WSDL may be helpful to see the expected requestand why it's not working.

Did you try using [PackageGenerator](https://github.com/WsdlToPhp/PackageGenerator)? Let me know then